# Como puedo acceder a los archivos en el almacenamiento externo de Android 11?

Tags: android, permisos

Tengo una app que se ejecuta perfectamente en cualquier dispositivo con sistema operativo Android en versiones anteriores a la versión 11. En la app manejo archivos que importo hacia el almacenamiento externo y exporto desde el almacenamiento externo. Pero cuando el dispositivo tiene Sistema Operativo Android 11 solamente tengo acceso a las carpetas pero no puedo ver los archivos que contienen estas carpetas.

El código que uso es el siguiente:

```
private void importarArchivo(File archivo) {
    boolean isCreate = false;

    if (archivo.isFile()){
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "SI EXISTE EL ARCHIVO"+archivo.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            importarPedidos(archivo);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }else  {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NO EXISTE EL ARCHIVO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void importarPedidos(File archivo) {
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(archivo);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "INCLUSO LO ASIGNA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Pedido pedido=null;

    while(true) {
        String cadena;
        String[] arreglo;
        cadena=null;
        try {
            if (!((cadena = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        arreglo = cadena.split(",");
        String lote=arreglo[4].toString();
        pedido=new Pedido();


        ConeccionSQLiteHelper admin = new ConeccionSQLiteHelper(getContext(), "Extraccion.db", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
        registro.put("numero", arreglo[0].toString());
        registro.put("fecha", arreglo[1].toString());
        registro.put("especie", arreglo[2].toString());
        registro.put("finca", arreglo[3].toString());
        registro.put("lote",arreglo[4].toString());
        registro.put("equipo", arreglo[5].toString());
        registro.put("traccion", arreglo[6].toString());
        registro.put("supervisor", arreglo[7].toString());
        registro.put("jefeproceso", arreglo[8].toString());
        registro.put("jefelinea", arreglo[9].toString());
        registro.put("estimadop", Integer.valueOf(arreglo[10].toString()));
        registro.put("estimadot", arreglo[11].toString());
        registro.put("producidop", arreglo[12].toString());
        registro.put("producidot", arreglo[13].toString());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Pedido: "+arreglo[1]+" "+arreglo[2]+" "+arreglo[3], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // los inserto en la base de datos
        //db.insert("Pedidos", null, registro);

        Long idResultante=db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_SOLICITUDES,Utilidades.CAMPO_IDSOLICITUD,registro);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Id Registro: "+idResultante,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        db.close();

    }
}
```

Y la rutina de permisos para acceder a los archivos es:

```
public void pedirPermisos() {
    // PERMISOS PARA ANDROID 6 O SUPERIOR
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                        {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},0);
    }
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                        {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},0);
    }
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                        {Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},0);
    }
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},0);
    }
}
```

En las versiones de Android anteriores a la 11 funciona perfectamente. Pero en dispositivos con Sistema Operativo Android 11 me deja ver las carpetas y navegar entre ellas pero los archivos no me los deja ver. Quiero saber si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema que presentas no es propio de Android 11, se definió que a partir de la API 29 (android 10) ya no se tendrá acceso a ubicaciones fuera del directorio de tu aplicación, ahora tendrás que crear directorios y archivos dentro de la estructura definida por Android.

Por lo tanto únicamente podrás escribir archivos dentro de la siguiente estructura de tu dispositivo:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files/
```

Puedes definir temporalmente el atributo `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` pero en algún momento deberás cambiar a leer los archivos dentro de la estructura definida por Google.

El archivo debe obtenerse de esta forma:

```
File myFile = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), "nombre archivo a leer");
FileReader fReader = new FileReader(myFile);
```

la creación del archivo se realizaría de esta forma:

```
 try {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "nombre archivo a crear");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```